# How to create NotesDatabase object using Lotus Notes Shared Mailbox

Tags: .net, lotus-notes, vb.net-2010, lotus-domino

```
Dim lotusnotessession As New NotesSession
Dim NotesDb As NotesDatabase
Dim InboxView As NotesView
lotusnotessession = New NotesSession()
lotusnotessession.Initialize(PWD)
NotesDb = lotusnotessession.GetDatabase(LNServer, LNFile, False)
```

When i open my lotus notes notesdatabase setting i see these details, but not sure how to connect to the Lotus Notes server using the below? this is a shared mailbox.Also .nsf file is not in my local server.

MailServer - XXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXX
Passthru Server - XXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: I think you need to restate your question. You have all of the correct syntax above. What is it that you don't know? Do you not know the name of the server that the shared mailbox is on? Do you not know the filename?  Something else?

Comment: Have you installed and configured the Notes client on your system? That process sets up the connection documents for accessing the server where the mailbox resides.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz after getting access for shared Mailbox its working thanks a lot for all your support